# Can't open display

Tags: display, vnc

Searched all over, but still cannot resolve this problem.

Ubuntu 18.04 installed on AWS. Use 'vncserver :1 -localhost=no' to start up a VNC server (TightVNC). Connect to vnc:(MyIP):5901 from my Mac - no problem.

A full desktop comes up in the viewer - shows Trash, File System, and Home folders. Can open them OK.

Can open a Terminal window, verify that DISPLAY=':1.0' is set as expected. But trying to run anything else (from within the Terminal window) - e.g. xclock - always gets:

- No protocol specified
- Error: Can't open display: :1.0

Tried both as a normal user and after 'su - root' - same results. Very puzzling since the VNC viewer is showing the whole desktop GUI exactly as expected.

From earlier searches already tried:

- xhost +
- made hostname all lower case
- made sure that hostname is in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
- made sure hostname is in /etc/hosts
- ran apt update & apt upgrade

Any ideas?